# CraftBukkit and slime spawn chunks?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bukkit

Does CraftBukkit change the default formula for which chunks can spawn slimes?

After installing CraftBukkit, I have not seen a single slime in my slime farm, and before I installed CraftBukkit, I could regularly visit it to pick up slimeballs.

Answer (score 2):

It's based on the seed (like biomes), so no.

However apparently there are map tools that will mark slime places for you on a generated map.

Comment: I know that there are map tools, I have used that (http://mcslimes.appspot.com/) to find the chunks near my base. When I visited my slime farm before "upgrading" to CraftBukkit, it regularly produced slimes and thus slimeballs. After installing CraftBukkit, there has been no slimes in it since. Hence my question. My question was if CraftBukkit perhaps managed to change the formula used to determine if a chunk could produce slimes, either by accident or by design.

Comment: @Lasse V. Karlsen — Change the formula?  Very unlikely. Change something else which prevents slimes from spawning at all?  Possibly; there are a number of Bukkit plugins which affect spawning.

Comment: I have only got Essentials (Bukkit Essentials, providing things like teleport and /home) installed. Perhaps I should try removing those temporarily to see what happens.

Comment: It's more likely that your seed was corrupted during your upgrade, which would move the slime chunks elsewhere. Have you used mcslime since your upgrade?

Comment: Yes, and I've verified that the seed, as reported by Minecraft, is the same. I also tried uploading my level.dat file to mcslimes, and it reported the same seed. I had the "EssentialsSpawn" plugin installed, I disabled that, still no dice. I'm going to try "vanilla" bukkit now and see if that helps.

Comment: http://forums.bukkit.org/threads/fun-fix-slimechunk-v1-1-did-you-know-this-is-not-a-slimechunk-then-make-it-to-one-1000-1060.27224/ Use that to test whether your spawner is in a slime chunk in game, and if it is then it's simply possible that the game mob spawning mechanics changed in 1.8 to prevent slimes from spawning. If you can be sure that your trap is in a slime chunk then I think the only other option is that the slimes simply aren't spawning.

Comment: I installed that, and entered my slimefarm, and I got "You entered a slime-spawning chunk", and "/slimechunk" tells me it does spawn slimes. Yet, no slimes. I will have to try without craftbukkit I think.

Comment: I think it's most likely at this point that the new mob spawning code is preventing slimes from respawning properly, or they're just doing spawning very very slowly. This is similar to the problem of the disappearance of passive mobs in popular SMP areas. Hopefully it will be fixed with the rest of the mob mechanics in 1.9.